# DPI Scaling on NixOS with LightDM + XMonad

Tags: x11, xserver, nixos, hidpi

I've stripped the xserver configuration on my HiDPI laptop down to just:

- `displayManager`: lightdm (autologin, no greeter)
- `windowManager`: xmonad
- `desktopManager`: none (xterm disabled)

And everything is working fine apart from DPI scaling in *some* places. Specifically: the cursor size and *default* tty font are both tiny. Apps - terminal emulators, Firefox, etc - are scaling fine as a result of my X settings (below).

Cursor size, and the slow movement that results, is the biggest pain.

So my question is: why would I see proper scaling in some places and not others? What is responsible for the cursor size and other "core" display stuff?

Stuff I've done/tried:

✓ `services.xserver.dpi = 180;` (sets `xserver` flag)

✓ .Xresources settings

```
Xft.dpi: 180
Xft.autohint: 0
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.rgba: rgb
```

✓ `export GDK_SCALE=2`

✓ `export GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.5`

✓ `export XCURSOR_SIZE=32`

✓ `export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1`

Relevant (?) GH issues:

- [nixpkgs#22652](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/22652)

---

Using NixOS 18.03

Answer (score 7):

Having struggled with this for a while, here are my conclusions...

Whatever black magic is at play making the mouse pointer do it's thing, it has *no concern* for DPI. In retrospect this seems kinda obvious. A mouse pointer moving across a screen is "lower-level" than a GUI application, such that DPI *per se* is irrelevant.

The fix? Bigger pointer icon (64x64 worked for me) and more sensitive movement (`libinput Accel Speed` in my case).

Comment: Have you made any headway?